# Return set of dates from hard-coded start point up to yesterday

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'd like to return the set of dates from the 18th of June up to yesterday. My attempt was as follows but I'm getting this error:

> Executing the query ...
>   A calculated member cannot be used as an operand of the Range operator ( : ).
>   Execution complete

```
WITH   
    MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastDay] AS
        Tail([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day].members,1)
    SET [Set_Dates] AS   
        {
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day].&[20130618]:
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[LastDay]
        }  
SELECT  
    NON EMPTY 
     [Set_Dates]  
    ON COLUMNS
FROM [myCube]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to play about with the formatting and dimension/attribute names, but try this:

```
SELECT
    NULL
ON COLUMNS,
{
    [Date].[Full Date].[2013-07-01] :
    STRTOMEMBER("[Date].[Full Date].[" + Format(DATEADD("d", -1, Now()),"yyyy-MM-dd") + "]", CONSTRAINED)
}
ON ROWS FROM [Cube]
```

Comment: +1 thanks Meff - I've not seen the `STRTOMEMBER` in action before - like it. I wonder though if everything on the right of the `:` can just be replaced with `null` ?

Comment: @whytheq if you do { [Date].[SomeDate] : NULL } it will be the calendar from that "some date" up to the end of the calendar, whenever that is. If that's what you want, then that'd work.

Comment: ...if the cube has not loaded data for yesterday then will `STRTOMEMBER("[Date].[Full Date].[" + Format(DATEADD("d", -1, Now()),"yyyy-MM-dd") + "]", CONSTRAINED)` cause an error?

Comment: @whytheq "Constrained" means you want to throw an error if the dimension member you are creating with StrToMember does not exist. You can remove the "Constrained" flag, then it'd work the same as NULL if it's missing - In that it'd run to the end of the calendar. Depending on what results you want in that situation, will guide whether you do that or not.